# Finding the resistivity of doped silicon sample

Tags: semiconductors

Given that the mobility of electrons and holes in silicon is given by equations 1 and 2, **I'm trying to find the resistivity** of a sample which has been doped with a donor density of:

$$N_d=2\times 10^{15}cm^{-3}$$ 
$$(1) \space \space μ_e=92+\frac{1270}{1+(\frac{N_d}{1.3\times 10^{17}})^{0.91}}$$
$$(2) \space \space μ_h=48+\frac{447}{1+(\frac{N_a}{6.3\times 10^{16}})^{0.76}}$$

**Here is my attempt:**

We know that drift current density is given by the following equation:

$$J=q(nμ_e+pμ_h)E$$

From here, we can easily get the resistivity:
$$(3)\space\spaceσ=\frac{E}{J}=\frac{1}{q(nμ_e+pμ_h)}$$

**Here is where I'm stuck:**

To apply equation 3 I need the electron density n and the hole density p. We can approximately say that n=Nd since the number of donors is much greater than the intrinsic density of free electrons. However, I still need p which (at least to my knowledge) I can only get from the equation:

$$p=\frac{n_i^2}{N_d}$$

Neither intrinsic density ni nor any information to calculate it are given by the problem. So, I can't find p. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Do you know the temperature? It seems pretty important to me. But it also seems that you present this as if what you show is all you have to work with. Which suggests you don't have the temperature.

Comment: @jonk No, nothing is mentioned about the temperature. I've included everything that is given. I'm starting to think the solution will depend on ni.

Comment: Well, let me suggest another thought. Even if you could compute \$p\$, I believe you are supposed to assume that \$n\gg p\$ and therefore you may assume to neglect it. But you'd know better than I if that's the case.

Comment: I did consider this scenario since minority carriers tend to be much less than majority carriers. Their mobility is smaller as well . However, such assumption would render equation 2 pointless. It wouldn't be the first time something unnecessary is provided in these problems I'm solving though...But, I suppose we covered all the scenarios now. I'll just write all these "thoughts" in my answer if I'm given such a problem in an exam.

Comment: That's all I can think of, here. I do think that assumption is often made in estimating resistivity. I've certainly seen it in problems. Your application of the mass-action law and the assumption (\$n=N_d\$) you made seem correct to me. I think, though, that you are supposed to follow through with that assumption and recognize that \$p\$ also isn't important in the solution. But... I don't know. Besides, I never took any classes on microelectronics (or even DC electronics.) I just read a few things and pick up a bit here and there. Perhaps someone here, better educated, can help you.